# SSL, netscaler and apache configuration help needed

Tags: apache, https, reverse-proxy, netscaler

I have a setup with Netscaler, plus apache 2.2.16 configured as a reverse proxy to tomcat servers.

I do  the SSL offloading at the Netscaler level, but my client has made a request  to redirect a  specifig page to their CRM login page thats using an SSL Cert. https://$ip

When the SSL is offloaded at the netscaler level, the virtual host received unencrypted traffic, but with the clients request, I need to enable the SSL engine on apache and put the  certs in the config, hence the proxy rejects the non encrypted traffic coming in on port 443.

I proxypass / to the backend.. so I am out of clue on how i should fix this particular problem.

Any comment or help are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If the traffic to the backend must be encrypted, there's no point in using the NetScaler for SSL offload. Just set up an SSL bridge on the NetScaler to pass the traffic through to the backend, and handle the redirection on the server.